# Why cant I use the Collections.max() function for this code? - java

Tags: java, sorting, generics, collections, comparator

I have 10 trees. Each tree has a few instance variables (space, grid, suitability, and id); a place in geographic space and on a grid, a value representing habitat suitability from 0 to 1, and an ID number respectively.

I have put these trees and their associated data into a ArrayList called trees. And then I have the system print out their ID and associated value of suitability. The code is below.

At the end, I want to print out the highest suitability value, but I keep getting an error under max saying:

> "Bound mismatch: The generic method `max(Collection<? extends T>)` of
>   type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments
>   (`ArrayList<Trees>`). The inferred type Trees is not a valid substitute
>   for the bounded parameter `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>`"

I cant seem to figure out what this means. Please let me know if you need to see more code.

Does anyone know how I can get the highest suitability value (the value closest to 1)?

```
int treeCount = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < treeCount; i++) {
    double suitability = RandomHelper.nextDoubleFromTo(0, 1);
    int id = i;
    context.add(new Trees(space, grid, suitability, id));

    ArrayList<Trees> trees = new ArrayList<Trees>();

    Trees tree;

    tree = new Trees(space, grid, suitability, id);
    trees.add(tree);
    System.out.println("Tree " + id + " has a suitability of " + suitability);

    Object obj = Collections.max(trees);
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the `max` method to find the _max_ value?

Comment: Does `Trees` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: If you are the author of `Trees` you need to make it implement `Comparable`. If you are not, you need to pass a `Comparator` to the `max` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have forgotten to implement [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).. Without doing so, there is no way of telling which tree is the "biggest"..

You might want to do it something like that:

```
public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tree o) {
        // use the value which should be used for comparison instead of getSuitability().
        // remember: here you have private access to object o. if your value is not a
        // double, there is also a Integer.compare(..) function, but you could also just
        // return value - other.value..
        return Double.compare(getSuitability(), o.getSuitability());
    }
    // .. code ..
}
```

If you can't modify the `Tree` class, you can always implement a [`Comparator<Tree>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public class TreeComparator implements Comparator<Tree> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Tree o1, Tree o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getSuitability(), o2.getSuitability());
    }
}
```

And use it along with the [`Collections.max(Collection, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) function:

```
Tree maxTree = Collections.max(trees, new TreeComparator());
```

<sub>If you are calling this code often, consider extracting the `new TreeComparator()` call to a constant.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Trees` is not comparable.

Think - how does `Collections.max(trees)` determine what the max tree is?

You have two options:

1. `Trees` implements `Comparable`
2. Implement a `Comparator` and call `Collections.max(trees, comparator)`